# GA API v4 странно работают несколько DimensionFilter (php)

Tags: php, google-analytics

Пытаюсь получить статистику по событию, используя GA APi v4 на php.
На странице стоит простой счетчик:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   ga("send", "event", "eventCategory", "eventAction", "eventLabel");
</script>
```

Я хочу получить количество срабатываний события по трем параметрам: eventCategory, eventAction и eventLabel. Делаю, как в гайде, в общем виде получается так:

```
function getReport($analytics) {
  // Создание объекта Metrics.
  $totalEvents = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Metric();
  $totalEvents->setExpression("ga:totalEvents");
  $totalEvents->setAlias("totalEvents");    

  $dimensionFilter = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_DimensionFilter();
  $dimensionFilter->setDimensionName('ga:eventCategory');
  $dimensionFilter->setOperator('EXACT');
  $dimensionFilter->setExpressions('My_event name');                        

  $dimensionFilter2 = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_DimensionFilter();
  $dimensionFilter2->setDimensionName('ga:eventAction');
  $dimensionFilter2->setOperator('EXACT');
  $dimensionFilter2->setExpressions('My_event_action'); 

  $dimensionFilter3 = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_DimensionFilter();
  $dimensionFilter3->setDimensionName('ga:eventLabel');
  $dimensionFilter3->setOperator('EXACT');
  $dimensionFilter3->setExpressions('My_event_label');  

  $dimensionFilterClause = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_DimensionFilterClause();
  $dimensionFilterClause->setFilters([$dimensionFilter, $dimensionFilter2, $dimensionFilter3]);     

  // Создание объекта ReportRequest.
  $request = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_ReportRequest();
  $request->setViewId($VIEW_ID);
  $request->setDateRanges($dateRange);
  $request->setMetrics(array($totalEvents));
  $request->setDimensionFilterClauses([$dimensionFilterClause]);
  $body = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_GetReportsRequest();
  $body->setReportRequests( array( $request) );
  return $analytics->reports->batchGet( $body );
}
```

Но я получаю странные результаты.

```
$dimensionFilterClause->setFilters([$dimensionFilter]);
```

Это получается все срабатывания моего My_event name. Ответ апи, totalEvents: 1737

```
$dimensionFilterClause->setFilters([$dimensionFilter, $dimensionFilter2]);
```

Так я ожидаю получить срабатывания моего My_event name, но у которого ga:eventAction = My_event_action Получаю в ответ от апи, totalEvents: 1738
То есть событий с заданным eventAction больше, чем всего событий...

```
$dimensionFilterClause->setFilters([$dimensionFilter, $dimensionFilter2, $dimensionFilter3]);
```

Ну, и напоследок фильтр по всем трем параметрам выдает снова 1737.

При такой настройке фильтров, я ожидаю получить количество вызовов события My_event name, у которых ga:eventAction = My_event_action, а ga:eventLabel = My_event_label Такое чувство, что когда фильтр один, то он работает корректно. А когда больше одного - в результате чтото непонятное =( 
Я чтото не правильно понимаю, или делаю не так? Как мне получить задуманную выборку?